# Set the frame on an armature

Tags: armature

I've found the scene function [frame_set](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_65_release/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=frame_set#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set) to be very slow.
Is there any functions to set the frame only on an armature/object ?

This is for an exporter where I advance the animation frame by frame.

Answer (score 1):

user preferences > Editing > Only insert needed enabled

[image]

Comment: Actually, I've already simplified all the F-curves with the Simplify addon. I'm exporting the animation and I advance it frame by frame, so I don't think it matters how many keyframes I have.

Answer (score 0):

`frame_set` is a python function used to change the current frame, when you change the frame every object in the scene needs to be updated to reflect their location at that point in the animation. For a large scene this can take some time.

If you only want to see the armature movement you can hide all un-selected objects <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to show them again, you can also go into local view, press <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> to toggle local view. By not having most objects visible can speed things up.

Comment: Yes this was what I thought too, but it made no difference. In the export script I've hidden all the object (meshes, camera ...) except for the armature (displayed as sticks) and it made no difference.